# Executing a non-package-provided binary on 16.04

Tags: command-line, 16.04, bash, executable, binary

I just installed 16.04 LTS on a laptop and wanted to install and execute a binary file compiled on a 14.04 64-bit system. To my dismay, none of my options worked. It didn't matter where I put it, it would detect the file but then say 'bash: /usr/bin/iperf2: No such file or directory'.

Fortunately, Synaptic identified that the iperf package is in fact iperf-2.0.5 so I was able to get past this one but I often need to build on our big 12.04-based build server and execute on a local machine so this issue will come up again.

Comment: If your executable depends on external libraries, you must install them. As the executable is not packaged, this can not be done automatically though, because the requirements are not included anywhere. You must do it yourself and find out what it needs either by trying or by checking the documentation, if available. Once you know all the dependencies, you could write a simple install script that installs all he dependency packages at once.

Comment: In this case, there were no external libraries.

UPDATE: I'm wrong; there are. That's probably the issue. Thank you, @ByteCommander!